# Why most wireless keyboard do not have led indicator?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I want to buy a wireless keyboard. However, most do not have LED indicator for numlock capslock and scroll lock. I wonder why.

Mac keyboard has that. Most wireless keyboard for PC doesn't. They can just turn of all those locks when not in used right?

I suspect it's to save power. That's what I suspected. However, it's such a small LED and only show up when the keyboards are actually in use. Also Mac keyboards have LED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LED consumes a suprising amount of power: 20 milliamps. Enough to run your batteries down noticeably more quickly.

Comment: That's what I suspected. However, it's such a small LED and only show up when the keyboards are actually in use. Also Mac keyboards have LED.

Comment: I wouldn't say you'll notice the effect, really. Mac keyboards only have a LED indicator for caps lock, so that doesn't really use any power whatsoever EXCEPT FOR WHEN YOU WRITE IN CAPS LOCK ALL DAY ;) @jim